# Python Script Not Finishing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run my code to try to solve euler problem number 10. I am very new to python and my code has been going very slowly and in this case never ending. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
primes = [2]
number = 2

y=1
while y <=1:
    for i in primes:
        if number % i == 0:
            break
        else:
            if i == primes[-1]:
                primes.append(number)
                if (primes[-1]) >= 2000000:
                    del primes[-1]
                    y += 2
    number+=1
print(sum(primes))
```

Comment: @Jacobr365 That is incorrect, the break goes to the line `number+=1` so the next iteration of the while loop the if statement will be `if 3 % 2 == 0` and the else will execute. But the y value never changes

Comment: @DonatPants Thanks. That's what I get for editing from phone. Didn't even notice that line. Deleting comment.

Comment: Your program does terminate but you didn't give it enough time, I changed the line `if (primes[-1]) >= 2000000:` to `if (primes[-1]) >= 200:` and the program terminated. make your program more efficient so that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

SPOILER ALERT: the following contains the answer to question 10 in Project Euler.

Your problem is that your code take too long to run, that is because it is checking too many thing and will take too long to work. In PE question you usually have to think of a trick to get your program to get the result fast enough. In this case you need to understand why there is no need to check weather a prime is divisible by a prime that is bigger the the square root of the number.

> If a number `x` was divisible by a prime number `p` that is bigger than the square root of `x`, that would mean that there is a natural number `n` that is `n = x/p`, if `p` is bigger than the square root of `x` then `n` is smaller than the square root of `x` (think about why this is true). That means that we would find that the number `x` is also divisible by the number `n` that is smaller than the square root of `x`. That means we would have already found that `x` is divisible by `n` (or a prime factor of n) when we were checking all the numbers that are smaller than the square root of `x`, therefor there is no need to check any number bigger then the square root of a number is order to know if it is prime Q.E.D .

This way you can save A LOT of computations.  the following is a python program that implements this idea:

```
import math

primes = [2]
is_prime = True

# loop over all the ODD numbers from 3 to 2,000,000 (no need to check even numbers)
for number in xrange(3, 2000000 + 1, 2):
    sqrt = math.sqrt(number)
    # loop over all the primes we have so far
    for prime in primes:
        # if the number we are checking is divisible by a prime it is not prime and we can move on to the next number
        if number % prime == 0:
            # we set this value to false so that when we finish the loop we will be able to know if the number is prime or not
            is_prime = False
            break

        # this line is where the clever part is, if we already checked `all the primes that are smaller than square root of x, and we did not find any primes that our number is divisible by, then we will not find any primes higher than the square root of the number that the number is divisible by`
        if prime > sqrt:
            break

    if is_prime:
        primes.append(number)
    else:
        is_prime = True

# we are done, print the answer
print sum(primes)
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I appreciate the detailed answer by @DonatPants, I believe that solution is too complicated.  First, we don't need to calculate `sqrt()` when the simpler square will do (I.e. square both sides of the equation.)  Second the order of tests seems backward, why check `prime > sqrt` after `if number % prime == 0`?  If `prime > sqrt`, you don't need the other test.  And what's with that boolean?  My simpler approach to this problem:

```
primes = [2]

for number in range(3, 2000000 + 1, 2):  # only test odd numbers

    for prime in primes:
        if prime * prime > number:  # we're past sqrt, a prime!
            primes.append(number)
            break

        if number % prime == 0:  # a composite
            break

print(sum(primes))
```

Redundantly computing `prime * prime` is an inefficiency.  It doesn't make any difference for this range of numbers but if needed, you can keep a separate array of squares, enumerate the primes and use the index generated to access the square, which you save when you save the prime.  Squaring just the primes is cheaper than square rooting all the numbers:

```
primes = [2]
squares = [4]

for number in range(3, 2000000 + 1, 2):

    for index, prime in enumerate(primes):
        if squares[index] > number:
            primes.append(number)
            squares.append(number * number)
            break

        if number % prime == 0:
            break

print(sum(primes))
```

We're wasting space to avoid wasting time.  But again, for this range of numbers, it's not worth it.

Comment: Your answer is better, the reason I wrote my answer this way is so that it will be a bit similar to the original code. In regards to the fact that  `" the order of tests seems backward"`, and `"we don't need to calculate sqrt() when the simpler square will do"`, I agree that your way is better. so if OP is reading this, I would recommend you use this code and not mine.